# In Grover's algorithm, how does the function know what element is to be searched for?

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm

In grover's algorithm the oracle gives the output 1 if the element we want is there, my question is, how does the function know what element is to be searched for or how do you put in the element you want to teach for specifically to the oracle?

In simple words, we manually design the oracle for the input we want it to search right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Grover's Algorithm, does the exact solution need to be given to the oracle?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7138/in-grovers-algorithm-does-the-exact-solution-need-to-be-given-to-the-oracle) (also see links therein)