Implementation of the Grover's oracle in a real life use case
Imagine a database of DNA fingerprints, each one characteristic of only one person. You
are given a DNA trace and asked to find the person to which it belongs. There is no way
(to my knowledge !) to sort DNA fingerprints so that you are left to compare each DNA
fingerprint of the database with your particular trace.
Given the size of such genetic database, this is where the Grover's algorithm may come
in handy. Grover's algorithm is based on an Oracle function which links the quantum
algorithm itself to the database and its queries.
Following figure is an attempt to represent the Grover's algorithm,
definitely lying on the Quantum side, with respect to the database itself, which lies in
the Classic world. In between is the database elements indexing, each element of the
database is assigned an index, regardless of its inner position in the database. Each
index is encoded in the quantum register.

On the Classic side, you can build a function $f$ with your particular DNA trace $T$,
which takes in input a database element $E$, and returns $1$ if $T$ and $E$ are
identical, i.e. belonging to the same person, or $0$ otherwise.
Oracle $O_{f}$ performs the evolution :
\begin{equation}
|y\rangle = |- \rangle \quad,\quad O_{f}(|\psi_{H}\rangle \otimes|y\rangle) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}|k\rangle 
\otimes|y \oplus f(k) \rangle = \dots =
\biggl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(-1)^{f(k)}|k\rangle \biggr)\otimes|- \rangle 
\end{equation}
which means that previous function $f$ is applied to each fundamental state of the
superimposed state $|\psi_{H}\rangle$. But then, this means we would have to call the classic
function $f$ for all indices and consequently for all database elements, which would
make useless the quantum algorithm ?
How do you concretely implements the oracle in such real life use cases ?

I have troubles with \ket{} in latex formulas, it does not render well on the published question, but $\ket{y}$ should be the correct syntax (?), or which one to use ? Regards

"| \psi \rangle"

I've changed them to | and \rangle

Thanks, I will keep notice of this.

Well, I'd start by debating your assertion that there's no way to sort DNA fingerprints. Any data that you have is written in some language, and you can sort it according to the lexicographic ordering of the alphabet you've used. (Searching for a 99% match might be a completely different matter!)
Nevertheless, if we take your proposal at face value, I think you have a basic misunderstanding of how we count the running cost in terms of oracle evaluations. Yes, the oracle, in some sense, gets evaluated for all possible inputs. But it does not do this one after the other. Each branch of the superposition only interrogates the oracle once. Hence, each branch takes the same time, and the total time is the time for one oracle call (for this single step. You will then have to repeat the step many times to complete the search).

Yes, but for one oracle iteration, you are to call the function f for all branches of the superposition, which you can probably do in parallel, and so if I understand you well, this counts for one step. But if you can make so many parallel calls to function f, what prevents you do doing it classically ? thus finding deterministically the search element in O(1) ?

Following this question : https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/175/how-is-the-oracle-in-grovers-search-algorithm-implemented, it seems that function $f$ would have to be implemented in a quantum circuit and then, that the whole database should be put in a quantum register too.

Yes absolutely, the function evaluation/database lookup needs to be capable of accepting a superposition as input, and maintaining coherence through that evaluation.

What prevents you from doing it classically is what you can do with the answers afterwards. You can only ever "see" one answer. The trick that quantum lets you perform is to give an answer that is a global function of many outputs. You can still only access a certain amount of information each time, but superpositions give you access to different information
