# Quantum machine learning: only a boost to computation or something more?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm new in the area and I'm quite curious.

- What are the main advantages of quantum machine learning over "classical" machine learning (from sklearn library, for example)?
- Is just only a boost to the computational process or it could be a way for building better models (in term of bias/variance trade-off - more generalized model)?
- Are the super-positions (and other quantum characteristics) a way for capturing better statistical properties (so, maybe, quantum computation can be used in a sort of "features engineering" step)?

thanks everyone!

Comment: [This](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13531/what-is-the-advantage-of-quantum-machine-learning-over-traditional-machine-learn) might be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to QCSE! If you have multiple questions, please submit them as multiple posts.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that!